# styled component in typescript throw error if i use custom props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have been trying to pass custom props to my styled component but typescript throws the error `Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type`. However, if I set `"strict: false"` I longer get the error.

Below is the code for reference.

```
interface TagProps {
  fontSize?: string
}

const Ptag = styled.p<TagProps>`
  font-size: ${(props) => (props.fontSize ? props.fontSize : "12px")};
`
```

Comment: So I guess you don't want to set `strict: false` and your question is : Why do I get this error and how I suppress it ?